# When a button on chrome extension DOM(popup.html) is clicked, extension DOM is closed and onclick function is not called in popup.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension to record the requests fired once I click on start button.

Here are my files:
1. manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "recorder",
  "description": "Recorder",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "webRequest",
    "<all_urls>",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "background"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persist" : true
  },

}
```

2. popup.html

   Here 2 buttons are created with id as "record" and "stop"
3. popup.js

   ```
   document.getElementById("record").addEventListener("click", startRecording);
   document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", stopRecording);

   function startRecording() {
        var RequestFilter = {};
        var  MatchPatterns = ['http://*/*', 'https://*/*'];

        RequestFilter.urls = MatchPatterns;

           RequestFilter.types = ['main_frame', 'sub_frame', 'object', 'xmlhttprequest', 'stylesheet', 'script' , 'image'];
           chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.addListener(onSendHeaders, RequestFilter,
           ['requestHeaders']);
   }


   function stopRecording() {
       chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.removeListener(onSendHeaders);
   }

   function onSendHeaders(info) {
         console.log(info.url);
   }
   ```

Now when I open the extension in chrome, a DOM opens up with 2 buttons on it. When I click the button with id as "record", extension DOM(popup.html) gets closed and nothing happens.

But when I right click and inspect the popup and then click on "record" button, popup.html remains open and URLs are printed on console.

expected behaviour is: When record button is clicked, extension should get minimised but the function called on button click should work until stop button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to do this using passing request between popup.js and background.js

I have used chrome.extension.sendRequest to send a Param type: 'start' in popup.js

In background.js I have added a listener onRequest that listen to the request sent.

This way I was able to record in background.

Answer (score 0):

can you bind click event after document is ready.

Comment: I am loading script after document is ready. I am writing script tag in popup.html at the end of body. It is calling the start recording function. I have added an alert in the function to check the same. But then recording is not being done.

Comment: document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById("record").addEventListener("click", startRecording);
  document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", stopRecording);
 })

This is how I am calling startRecording, but issue persists.